# iOS app developed from one Developer account and distribute it as enterprise app from another Enterprise account

Tags: ios, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution

I am developing an app from one developer account and it was going on for the last few months. But now the client want to distribute it to a few customers Off-Store. We have an enterprise account ready to use but my question is Should I do everything from the start again right from creating the App ID? Or any other way around?

I looked around internet for answers but I could find anything effective.

This one was quite related to my question but I was looking for Off-Store distribution only. I just want to know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is already configured in iTunes connect then you can transfer the app from one account to another account from iTunes Connect. Refer this and see if it helps your cause.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: I want to distribute this app in store through my Developer account but temporarily for some reason I want to distribute it to quite a few users outside the store.

Comment: @Matt would this be for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, you can say that

Comment: @Matt If you are doing this for testing purpose then you can use TestFlight External testing.

Comment: You can transfer it temporarily to the enterprise account and then transfer it back once its distributed to the people

Comment: @vivek App has to go through review process for external testing.

Comment: @PradeepK you have any idea how long will it take to transfer?

Comment: When you have sent the transfer request, the recipient has up to 60 days to sign into iTunes Connect and accept the offer. Once it has been accepted, Apple takes about two business days to complete the transfer. After this period, the app will no longer appear in the transferor's account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer provisioning profile for it.

1. Add UDID of device in developer provisioning profile.
2. Download and install developer provisioning profile.
3. After that build IPA by using this developer provisioning profile.
4. Upload the generated IPA to https://www.diawi.com and click send.
5. This will give you a link, from which you can download the app.

So you can share this link with anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not possible to get all users UDID.